# Why doesn't Sun do a C# to Java byte code compiler?

Tags: c#, java, .net, compiler-construction, jvm

### We Want to Run Our C# Code on the JVM

My company has a large C# code base. Well over half of this code is our core engine for creating, reading, modifying, calculating and writing Excel workbooks. We frequently get questions from customers and potential customers asking whether we are going to build a Java version of our engine - many of them are not at all interested in the UI. We even have a few customers who have taken the trouble to use our .NET library from their Java applications.

So, we would like to build a Java version of our core engine, ideally without maintaining a separate Java source code base.

Eric Sink [described this problem](http://www.ericsink.com/bos/Geeks_Rule.html) very well. I am in a similar position except for the fact that our software license includes royalty free deployment, making Eric's choice of Mainsoft a nonstarter for us.

I have been Googling the likes of ["c# to jvm"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22c%23+to+jvm%22&aq=f&oq=) every few months for several years now with no joy. Having spent ~7 years developing similar software for Java, I am confident that the .NET APIs we use in our core engine could easily be encapsulated and we could accomplish everything we need using the Java libraries. So, if we only had a C# -> JVM compiler we could build our core engine for Java and we would no longer have to turn away Java developers who would like to use it.

I am not asking for the technical reasons why Sun does not do a C# compiler. I recognize that Java has no properties or an unsigned 64 bit long, etc... For the sake of argument, just assume that all of these technical issues could be dealt with by extending the JVM and / or other means.

And I am not asking for yet another debate on why one language / stack might be better than the other. The reality in our business is that there are plenty of potential customers using each.

### Why Should Sun do a C# Compiler? (IMO of course)

Making it easier to run C# code on the Java platform means more developers and more software for the platform. Is there anything more important to the success of a platform? [Jonathan Schwartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_I._Schwartz) is a software guy. I will leave it to others smarter than me to decide whether or not he took on an impossible job as President and CEO of Sun, but having met with Jonathan shortly after he joined Sun my impression is that he understands software and the need for a large base of developers.

### So Why Doesn't Sun do a C# Compiler?

1. [NIH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Invented_Here) syndrome?
2. The ghost of [Scott McNealy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_McNealy)?
3. Too many Java developers dislike or distrust anything related to Microsoft?
4. They agreed not to as part of taking [the big bucks](http://www.internetnews.com/bus-news/article.php/3334991)?
5. ???

There must be a good reason. I just cannot for the life of me figure out what it is...

Comment: this is not a technical question, it's asking us to read the minds of Sun executives - my Kreskin program says they don't like C#, they like Java, and want the two to remain distinct, otherwise they cannot justify their existence

Comment: My #1 and #2 suggestions above go along with your Amazing insight. With the current Pres of Sun being a software guy, who knows, maybe we'll get an Amazing answer from the top?

Comment: Should Sun "embrace and extend" C# instead of pretending that it doesn't exist. I've been in the biz of developing software for other developers since before Gosling noticed his Oak tree and it seems to me that embracing C# would be a good thing - but maybe I drink too much of the Microsoft Koolaid?

Comment: There was a project a while ago in Sun to run VB code on the JVM. They lost interest though - probably as a result of lack of developer interest. Sun have enough on their plate with all the Dynamic languages they are supporting: JRuby, JPython etc

Comment: You could just port it to Java and drop the minority platform.

Comment: Tom - I did the Java thing from 1996 until 2002. My official reason for leaving Actuate? Microsoft understood the need for basic things like enumerated types (since added to Java but it took way too long) and excellent Windows UI support and Actuate had no interest in building .NET products.

Comment: Fortyrunner - No doubt that Ruby, Python and such are hot these days. I've been too busy starting a company to play with a new language for a while so I haven't had time to play with the new Dynamic languages...maybe it takes an obsessed advocate inside of Sun for any of these to succeed.

Comment: It may be a long shot, but have you looked into leveraging the Stab programming language? It basically IS C# for the JVM. Seems to me you could just about write some Java class wrappers, try to compile your code as Stab and *almost* get away with it? Of course I've never tried such a thing so I could be way off.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Firstly Sun has zero incentive to implement a C# compiler on the JVM because they have something very similar called the Java programming language.

Its also not really as simple as just implementing a compiler as the Java standard class libraries are not the same as the .net Base Class Libraries. You would end up having to change all the .NET API calls to Java API calls.

Micrsoft had a product called J# which was meant to be for Java to .NET conversion but in the end no one used it as the API was limited to pre Java 2 API so it was mostly useless. It would be the same if Sun implemented parts of the .NET BCL, as only the core portions of it are standardised and royalty free. Parts like ASP.NET and WPF, WCF etc are not part of the ECMA standards and so Sun would need Microsofts permission to implement those API's.

If enough customers want a java version to make business sense to port your application to java then do it, you just wont ever get any help from Sun via a C# to JVM compiler.

Comment: Yes, Java is similar, but we would like to make our core engine available and we don't want to maintain C# and Java code bases. The reality is that we, and many other companies, have C# code bases today that would arguably be more likely to run on Java someday if there were a C# compiler.

Comment: In my post I pointed out that we want to port our core engine and we could easily encapsulate the .NET APIs we use and use Java APIs on the Java platform. Having said that, we might be the exception and the lack of .NET libraries might make C# a dead end language just as you point out J# is.

Comment: I think if you want a Java version you are going to have to bite the bullet and port to Java. I doubt there will ever be a high quality C# compiler for the JVM. Without a good compiler there is not point even thinking about it. Sorry.

Comment: Wait... C# is a dead-end language? Now *that's* a riot!

Comment: If we had to start today we'd definitely do it in Java. I am afraid your are correct that we are unlikely to ever get a high quality C# compiler for the JVM.

Comment: Randolpho - oops, guess I wasn't too clear - how about "the lack of .NET libraries for the JVM might make a C# to JVM compiler a dead end project."

Comment: Ok, that I agree with. The APIs are very incompatible.

Comment: Actually Sun DOES have incentive to make C# run on Java. Sun makes their money off HARDWARE, not software. If C# stuff ran on the JVM, possibly they'd sell more Sun SPARCstations to run that C# on JVM code.

Comment: They might as well offically support mono on solaris than port C# and the .NET BCL to the JVM. If Sun were to implement the ECMA 334/335 standards your apps sill would not run as they use parts which are not part of that standard. Those other parts require MS licensing, I doubt that would happen.

Comment: @Robert: I agree with Tim; Mono on Solaris is the best way to allow C# on a Sun platform.

Answer (score 21):

> Joe Erickson wrote:
>
> Making it easier to run C# code on the
>   Java platform means more developers
>   and more software for the platform.

This is an untrue statement. Running C# code on the JVM does not create Java programmers, it creates C# programmers who can execute on a JVM. It only expands the reach of C#, assuming the JVM also translates any microsoft specific calls (i.e. win32) into something that is platform neutral. So if Sun translates IL to Java Bytecode, the only group it helps is: Microsoft. And, given Sun's history with Microsoft during the original C#-Java schism/Visual J++ lawsuits...

Plus, you have to face the technical infeasibility, whether you want to or not. There are fundamental differences in the way the bytecodes are executed that are far more important issues than whether or not there's an unsigned long datatype.

If you must have C# on a non-Microsoft platform, use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Comment: IMO Sun does not want to create Java programmers. They want developers writing software for their platform whether it's C or C++ or Java or Ruby or Python - but maybe not C#?

Comment: You and I disagree on technical feasibility. Mainsoft is a small ISV who manages to convert .NET assemblies to Java jar files. If a small ISV can do it - with no ability to change the JVM - certainly Sun can do it if they choose to.

Comment: I've only just realized that my last two paragraphs were probably off-topic. The original poster wants a compiler of C# to JVM bytecode, not an IL bytecode translator. I'll leave the post as is, but consider that part retracted. :)

Comment: And then I see replies. Heh. I see what you mean, but I don't think Sun has any real incentive, especially if an ISV has already done it for them.

Comment: I will look into mainsoft, however.

Comment: The problem with Mainsoft, as Eric Sink pointed out in the article referred to, is that they have "Enterprise Pricing" which means that a five man ISV such as my company is not the kind of customer they are looking for. Their product is very expensive.

Comment: It also looks like it's not really automatic; my first guess is that they do it manually. I'm listening to their integration webcast now.

Comment: Unfortunately, the people who ask us for a Java version of our engine are not interested in a Mono solution - if they were we would not be thinking of going to all the trouble of doing a Java version.

Answer (score 21):

Why doesn't **Microsoft** do a C# to Java byte code compiler? Why don't **you** do it? There are open specs on each side...

Comment: I wish Microsoft would do it! I think we all have a sense for the reasons why they won't.

I would love to do it, but I've got about 100 years worth of ideas which relate to problems I'm already obsessed with...so that's just not going to happen.

Comment: Now, MICROSOFT has no incentive to do this as they DO make money off software (quite a bit, too). Hardware companies try to commoditize the software, software companies try to commoditize the hardware.

Comment: Their incentive would be to try and kill Java. Offering backwards compatibility with the competition was how they killed Netwear, remember.

Answer (score 14):

*"So, we would like to build a Java version of our core engine, ideally without maintaining a separate Java source code base."*

Basically, you want to compile your C# code unmodified, and have it run in a Java-only environment.

IKVM *is not* what you want.  [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) is [three main things](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/tools.html).

a. ikvm - CLI implementation of a Java virtual machine (note that [this uses <s>Classpath</s>](http://weblog.ikvm.net/story.aspx/faq) (now OpenJDK) for the Java class library).

b. ikvmc - Compiles java bytecode to CLI bytecode.

c. ikvmstub - Generates java stub classes that call CLI code.

Note that all of these tools depend on CLI at runtime.  What you want is exactly the opposite of IKVM, which is of course MVKI (Most Venerable Kompiler Intermediary) :):

a. mvki - Java implementation of a CLI virtual machine (presumably this would use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) or [DotGNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/) for the class library).

b. mvkic - Compiles CLI bytecode to Java bytecode.

c. mvkistub - Generates CLI stub classes that call Java

Note that none of these would require an existing implementation of the .NET Framework at runtime, so they should be satisfactory to your Java-only customers.

Unfortunately, as far as I know MVKI does not exist, so you're best off doing a manual port (which would inevitably be cleaner, albeit more work).

Edit: Based on [the description](http://www.ericsink.com/bos/Geeks_Rule.html) of Mainsoft, it appears to be similar to MVKI, though I'm not sure what they do for the class library, and unlike IKVM it's not FOSS.

Comment: Agreed - as it stands today a port and ongoing maintance of two code bases would seem to be our best option. We have plenty of opportunities on the .NET side which allow us to leverage our C# engine, so this where we will invest our time.

Comment: IIRC the JVM is in effect a CPU so what would be needed would be not a JVM based CLI VM but a CLI JIT that targets the JVM (more or less)

Comment: BTW IKVM no longer uses GNU Classpath. It switched to Open JDK some time ago.

Answer (score 10):

http://jsc.sourceforge.net/ is a c# cross compiler that can convert .NET code to Java (amongst other things).

Comment: +1 Interesting!  Have you used this for transformation of non-trivial/production code?

Answer (score 7):

Expose your .NET API as ASMX web services and you should be good to go.

EDIT: For more heavy-usage scenarios, it would be worth looking into Windows Communication Foundation (WCF). This has built-in, configurable support for security, streaming, different transport scenarios (HTTP, TCP/IP, local named pipes). You are not restricted to SOAP message encoding, but that would probably be the easiest way to interop with Java.

I'm not too sure about your exact scenario, but if you're dealing with large files and the .NET code and Java code are both running locally, you can just save the file to the user's hard drive using .NET and then fetch it from your Java app.

Comment: This is a good suggestion which we will certainly do eventually (we've already been playing with Windows Azure with this in mind).  However, this is not a solution for many of our potential customers for performance (we have customers with 500MB workbooks) and / or security reasons.

Comment: I guess I would need to know more about your application requirements. It sounds like you might want to look into using Windows Communication Foundation (WCF). This is MS's new web services platform, which has built in support for security, MTOM streaming, TCP/IP binding, etc.

Comment: note that WCF doesn't do 'interoperable' tcpip: it only supports "optimised" connections to other WCF services, so it'll be just as bad for performance as a webservice. Maybe they'll change this in the future, but until then roll your own. (or use gsoap and a c++/cli wrapper)

Comment: Check out whether you can MTOM from Java to WCF? If it possible I would build a WCF service. I would never build an asmx web service, asmx is obsolete.

Comment: This is how i would do it, I would use WCF (BasicHttp Binding) over port 80 (WebService). I have made a call from just the Http get from this.

Answer (score 3):

> There must be a good reason. I just cannot for the life of me figure out what it is...

It is easy to believe that companies are non-profit organisations which have your interests at heart. It is easy to forget that the *only* purpose for a listed company is to make money for it share holders.  This is a legal obligation and directors/executives have been sacked/sued if share holders don't believe they have failed to do this.

Sun makes Java free because it helps sell their hardware which how it makes money from Java.  IBM makes Java free because it helps them make more money on their consulting.

If Sun were to spend money on a C# converter how would it make that money back and make a profit. Imagine you have to convince Sun's share holders.  If you can, Sun will make a C# converter.

Comment: I run my own for profit company so I do understand the need to make a profit. It seems to me that Sun is (was if the Oracle deal closes) interested in having as much software as possible run on their JVM and therefore on their hardware. Making it easier to get C# code running on the JVM would arguably make more software available.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder whether the Mono project could have made less work for themselves by targeting the JVM instead of developing and maintaining their own virtual machine from scratch.  Development effort could have focused on a C# cross-compiler and porting clean-room implementations of the .NET libraries to the JVM.  Sort of like an open-source version of what Mainsoft has done.  You could then enable inter-language calls between Java and C# code in the same JVM, and deploy Applets and Java Web Start applications written in C#.

Comment: That's a great question. Of course, it's too late now. I wonder if they considered it. I'm guessing that performance would be a big issue - no value types for example.

Comment: It is just not technically possible at this point to implement the C# spec on the JVM. C# supports pointers, unsigned types, user defined value types, true generics, passing by reference, and loads of other things. For a very C#-like JVM language, check out Stab: http://code.google.com/p/stab-language/

Answer (score 2):

I know this might not be what your looking for, but here are some possible alternatives that (if not to you) could be useful to others.

1. C: You could port as much as possible to C. Now you can make a wrapper in C# and Java (and any other language that can communicate with C) that makes it feel native to their language while programming. The problem now is that you (or them, depending your license) has to build the C part for each platform.
2. [Fantom*](http://fantom.org/): A programming language that according to their home page,
   is:

   > - Portable: Write code portable to the Java VM, .NET CLR, and    JavaScript in the browser.
   > - Familiar: Syntax Java and C# programmers will feel at home with    Fantom's evolutionary syntax.
   > - Object Oriented: Everything subclasses from Obj. Value types when you    need the performance.
   > - Functional: Functions and closures are baked in.
   > - Static and Dynamically Typed: Don't like the extremes - take the middle    of the road.
3. [Haxe](http://haxe.org/)*: (pronounced hex) is cross platform language that compiles to other languages.  Soon C# and Java will be supported. It currently supports:

   > - **Javascript:** You can compile a Haxe program to a single .js file. You can access the typed browser DOM APIs with autocompletion
   >     support, and all the dependencies will be resolved at compilation
   >     time.
   > - **Flash:** You can compile a Haxe program to a .swf file. Haxe is compatible with Flash Players 6 to 10, with either "old" Flash 8 API
   >     or newest AS3/Flash9+ API. Haxe offers very good performance and
   >     language features to develop Flash content.
   > - **NekoVM:** You can compile a Haxe program to NekoVM bytecode. This can be used for server-side programming such as dynamic webpages
   >     (using mod_neko for Apache) and also for command-line or desktop
   >     applications, since NekoVM can be embedded and extended with some
   >     other DLL.
   > - **PHP:** You can compile a Haxe program to .php files. This will enable you to use a high level strictly-typed language such as haXe
   >     while keeping full compatibility with your existing server platform
   >     and libraries.
   > - **C++:** You can now generate C++ code from your Haxe source code, with the required Makefiles. This is very useful for creating native
   >     applications, for instance in iPhone development.

   Haxe Community. (2011, March 11). Haxe Introduction. Retrieved January 29, 2011, from http://old.haxe.org/doc/intro

   You can learn more about why Haxe is useful [here](http://old.haxe.org/doc/why).

*I have never used this language and I don't know how well this would work.

Answer (score 1):

I made a comment that should really have been an answer:

It is just not technically possible at this point to implement the C# spec on the JVM. C# supports pointers, unsigned types, user defined value types, true generics, passing by reference, and loads of other things. For a very C#-like JVM language, check out [Stab](http://code.google.com/p/stab-language/).

[Mainsoft](http://harmon.ie/OtherProducts) fakes it. I am sure it takes enormous effort on their part.

Answer (score 0):

Have fun.

1. Must break checked exceptions.
2. Must find a way to implement delegates (which are like single-method interfaces added no earlier than load time).

Comment: Since C# code must assume that any method can throw any exception, the compiler could simply emit byte code which indicates that function F() throws any checked exceptions thrown by methods called by F() (hmmm...I remember doing a lot of essentially this same thing by hand back in the day).

Comment: As for delegates, the proper way to do it would be to extend the JVM. It could be done without extensions but it (emitted byte code) probably wouldn't be pretty or efficient.

Comment: That is no problem. Checked exceptions are a property of the Java language, not of the JVM. Other JVM languages havn't checked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** run your .NET code and Java code in the same interpreter! See the [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) .NET-based JVM, and the [Boo and Java](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BOO/Boo+And+Java) wiki page for an example use case (using the .NET-based Boo language to write applications using Java libraries).

Comment: Unfortunately, our potential customers are Java developers who want something which works in their current Java environment - whether it's a web server, application server, Applet, Java GUI app or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Joe, I suggest you [investigate IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/). You might find something there that scratches your itch

Comment: I've seen it - but it's not what we need. Unfortunately, our potential customers are Java developers who want something which works in their current Java environment - whether it's a web server, application server, Applet, Java GUI app or whatever

Comment: IKVM has a runtime dependency on CLI, which Joe already said he doesn't want.  See my post for the gory details.

Comment: Well, unfortunately there never is a free lunch. There's nothing in it for Microsoft to build a compiler to Java and Sun for sure won't do it. A compromise must be made somewhere to solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you will find that the [Mainsoft, Enterprise Edition](http://mainsoft.com/products/vmw_j2ee.aspx) tool allows you to run most/maybe all your .NET code under the Java JVM**... Seems to be focused more on ASP.NET but will allow C#. It has been available for some time, pity they don't publicize it better!

Warning blurb follows....

> Mainsoft® is Java-.NET
>   interoperability software that enables
>   IT organizations to move to
>   Java-enabled platforms such as Linux
>   while preserving existing investments
>   in .NET code and skills. The software
>   integrates seamlessly into the Visual
>   Studio® development environment,
>   enabling C# and Visual Basic
>   developers to rapidly develop and
>   maintain server and Web applications
>   that run on Windows, Java EE platforms
>   or both, thereby reducing application
>   development and maintenance costs,
>   time-to-production and total cost of
>   ownership.

Comment: If you read the original post, you will see that I refer to Mainsoft and the reason why it's a nonstarter for us.

Comment: so you do... sorry. Anyway it would be of interest to others.

Comment: It costs $5,000 per CPU on Tomcat and $15,000 per CPU on WebSphere Application Server, plus $6,000 per developer seat.... $11000 ^#$(@^$@&$$@%# NO THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

If i was doing something like cross platform cross language support, I would create a 'common api' since the languages are similar in syntax you could make a translator easy enough.  Then instead of calling java or .net apis directly from the core, you would call your 'common api' which would re implement the java and .net apis you would need.  In this way you could create a cross language sandbox if you will.  Since the main differences in java and c# are object definitions, I would get those by reflecting the C# dlls, and then reconstruct the constructs, then it would be easy to have an interpreter run through and implement the function bodies and convert properties to getters setters already knowing the structure of the files.  This of course is assuming .net 2.0, some of the features in 3.0 and 3.5 become very difficult to 'interpret'

It would be complex, but probably not as complex as reconstructing a core in java by hand, and having to have 2 teams working on them seperatly.  If this idea sparks some inspiration i might create one.  I would really rather see a simpler stable mono installation for mac.

Basically I think a code level interpreter based on a set of common api classes is something very possible to write with a team in a week or two.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.  Because Sun would rather not be sued by Microsoft.  And while we as programmers might see no viable reason for a suit, keep in mind that Microsoft is quite a bigger company than Sun and has the power to boss them around.

Sun fortunately is in the position of being quite more open than Microsoft however.  If such a demand exists, either open source or a third-party could make this compiler for Java and Sun wouldn't have to take the heat.

Answer (score 0):

[JACIL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacil/) is an apparently dead project that attempts to do the reverse of IKVM.  Perhaps some motivated folks could use it as a starting point for a viable .Net to JVM compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the better question is why don't **you** write a C# to Java byte code compiler, if you want one to exist.  Waiting for corporate overlords to do something is a bad idea.

A suggestion for creating such an implementation: take Mono's or .GNU's C# front end.  Don't bother writing your own.

Comment: We will not do a C# to Java byte code compiler because we have many years worth of work to do while staying focused on what we do best - which is spreadsheet technology.