# A .net wrapper for Google App Engine?

Tags: java, .net, python, web-services, google-app-engine

Does anyone know of a .net wrapper around either python or java Google App Engine services?

Any help appreciated // :)

Comment: Consider rephrasing or clarifying your question. It looks like people may not be understanding. Do you want to run .Net code (e.g. C#) on App Engine, or do you want to run existing App Engine code from an internal .Net server? Or perhaps something else totally? (Both situations I described are nearly hopeless for production by the way.)

Comment: I think what I'm looking for is something that lets you write .net and then spits out python web services or java web services that could work with GAE. Does that help?

Comment: python is available in .net (ironpython). Could you explain exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to understand specifics of how .net devs are interacting with GA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's impossible to run .net on GAE. At least, it's not impossible to run something that was generated from .net sources or interprets them at runtime. Just think about Ruby or Python, both work on the JVM (using JRuby and Jython). You'll probably have to look for something similar or try to cross-compile you .net code to Java class files.

Here is a related question: [Why doesn’t Sun do a C# to Java byte code compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494389/why-doesnt-sun-do-a-c-to-java-byte-code-compiler). Some people suggest using [JaCIL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacil/) or [jsc](http://jsc.sourceforge.net/). I didn't try those myself, but I'd bet you'll have to get your hands dirty to get something to work.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty close to what I was after :)

Comment: you don't need jython. python is supported by google app engine and there's a Google App Engine SDK for Python:

http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/downloads.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this is even *conceivable* (if I understand what you're asking about): App Engine will run code on a Python virtual machine or a Java one, never on a .NET one, so where would this "wrapper" *run*?  If your need is for .NET "in the cloud", consider [Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/azure/default.mspx) (you could run .NET on Amazon Web Services, I guess, given AWS's flexibility -- but if you're married to MS's platform anyway, why not use *their* cloud...?).

Answer (score 0):

Python has a .NET alternative called IronPython. But I don't think it will work in GAE as it supports only pure python. I am also facing a similar problem trying to port a source written in C#.net into GAE compatible code. I'm going to work around it by re-inventing the spokes of the wheel (not the wheel itself) by re-doing the UI using SVG or some other method. Have you considered that?