# Google App engine and .net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A .net wrapper for Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541722/a-net-wrapper-for-google-app-engine)

is there a C# .net wrapper for google app engine? or any third party tool to install in Visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently as far as I know, there are none available.

If you just want to access Google App  by login and logout, see this blog: http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=894

Answer (score 4):

No there is no C# .net wrapper for google app engine as for now and [Java/Python/Go](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/) are the official way to develop apps for now.
There is an issue filed for that. You can track that and see if and when it would be available:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8

There does exist an alternate way to do [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541722/a-net-wrapper-for-google-app-engine) but that my guess is this approach wouldn't be without issues.